# Null reference exceptions in .net

Tags: .net, wpf

we're having this big problem with our application. It's a rather large application with several modules, and thousands and thousands lines of code. A lot of parts of the application are designed to exist only with a reference to another object, for example a Person object can never exists without a House object, so if you at any point in the app say:

```
bool check = App.Person.House == null;
```

`check` should always be `false` (by design), so, to keep using that example, while creating modules, testing, debugging, App.Person.House is never null, but once we shipped the application to our client, they started getting a bunch of `NullReferenceException` with the objects that by design, should never have a null reference. They tell us the bug, we try to reproduce it here, but 90% of the times we can't, because here it works fine.

The app is being developed with C# and WPF, and by design, it only runs on Windows XP SP 3, and the .net framework v3.5, so we KNOW the user has the same operative system, service pack, and .net framework version as we do here, but they still get this weird `NullReferenceExceptions` that we can't reproduce.

So, I'm just wondering if anyone has seen this before and how you fixed it, we have the app running here at least 8 hours a day in 5 different computers, and we never see those exceptions, this only happens to the client for some reason.

ANY thought, any clue, any solution that could get us closer to fixing this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to confirm that the null reference exceptions are occurring where you think they are (i.e. in the line of code you specified above)?  If you are checking for nulls first, it doesn't seem likely that the problem is occurring there.

Comment: Yes, we have a log for all the exceptions, and we get a lot of details that help us know where the exception occurred (file name, method name, line number).

Comment: This is very difficult to answer, because all you've given us is a bunch of assumptions. Most likely, at least one of them is wrong...

Comment: Can you post some of the offending code?

Comment: Where are the `Person` and `House` objects coming from? Are these created from external data like a database? I assume that your client will use different data and that you only have some test data (which obviously won't cause the problem as you used them for testing).

Comment: @Thorarin I know they are assumptions, but that's as far as we can get, since like I said 90% of the time we can't rep these exceptions, and we never see them ourselves, even though we run / test the application collectively 40 hours a day (8 hours in 5 computers).

Comment: It sounds like a data problem to me.  They're putting data somewhere in a different way than you expect.

Comment: You are capturing and logging the stack trace whenever your application throws an exception, right?

Comment: @0xA3 Person and House (these are analogies of the real objects for simplicity) are serialized / deserialized in XML files, using the XmlSerializer class.

Comment: And the same XML file that your customer uses are available to you?

Comment: @Robert Rossney yes we're logging the exceptions

Comment: @0xA3 yeah but those are usually fine, the null reference problems happen once the objects have been deserialized, we've had problems with serialization / deserialization but we've been able to rep / fix those

Comment: What are the stack traces in your exception logs telling you?

Comment: @Robert Rossney It doesn't tell us who set the object to null, just who called the method once that object was null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you haven't really told us much about the House property... is it writable? If so, put validation into the setter which at *least* logs if the value is null - and ideally throw an `ArgumentNullException` immediately (I believe it's generally better to stop when your data is corrupt rather than continuing and hoping life will sort itself out). If it's just set to a backing field in a constructor, check it there - and again, throw `ArgumentNullException` if it's null.

If it's computed in some way, that makes it harder - at that point you should probably test in the getter and log (in some way that will be easy for your customers to get the information back to you) as much information as you think might be relevant.

EDIT: As has been pointed out, this could apply at any level within the expression - so you may well want to apply the same sort of validation and logging to each level.

Comment: I really love this idea... if it's ever null we'll stop it right there and log it. Our logger uses the StackTrace class, so it would tell us which object tried to set it to null. Thanks Jon, you've done it again!

Comment: Actually it won't necessarily.  As Henk Holterman observes, `App` or `App.Person` could be null and you'd get the same exception.  And if they are, code you put in the `House` setter will never get executed.

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
 bool check = App.Person.House == null;
```

will throw a null-ref exception when either `App` or `App.Person` is null.

You say 'cannot be null by design' but that is impossible to verify from your description. It seems clear though that you user(s) simply follow a path through your program that is not covered in your test-cases.

If you cannot spot the flaw in your design then the practical approach would be to extend your app with internal checking. I would recommend a good tracing system and (a lot of) `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Assert(xx != null);`

Answer (score 0):

How do you instantiate your objects? Could it be that the Person object is null? Or even the App object? That would explain the exceptions.

If you can't find the problem, I would suggest you add logging to the application and check if the code that instantiates your objects and the code that uses it to see if you somehow access the objects before they are created.

Another possible problem may be exception handling. Make sure you don't have try-catch blocks that just swallow the exception. These can be the source of some real headaches.

Anyway. These are just suggestions. Without knowing more about your system it is hard to make a better guess.

Answer (score 0):

One very tentative guess is that you have coded yr without a consistent exception handling pattern, and some other exception is being thrown and inappropriately swallowed, which allows the thread of execution to reach a point where code is running that assumes the object has been instantiated, when in fact the previously swallowed or ignored exception has somwhow prevented it from being instantiated, and caused it to still be null.

Comment: hmmm good point, I think jon's idea will help out track these null references.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing why this happen is really hard without understanding the code. Typical sources are

- access unitialized values (left to default null), but usually the C# compiler warns you
- casts (object as Type) when object is an unexpected type, these are usually quickly find in early testing, unless you have a completely untested code path
- allocation failures. In CLR though they raise OutOfMemoryException
- database reads. These are most likely culprit for primitive values, but not for complex classes. ORM layer though may mask the errors and simply assign nulls to members, triggering the errors you see much later
- logic errors. Another likely culprit , the way ur client uses the app exercises a different code path that simply doesn't assign the value

When I was faced with similar problems, I ended up adding instrumentation to the application. Primarily, logging ([log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) in my case) and exception reporting. Initially I used Assert, but the CLR asserts are a disaster in production as they pop up the big interrupt message box that requires user interaction and are completely unsuitable for services and background running apps. So I prefer to catch exception, create a report from the exception context, and send the report back to the mothership for analysis. Eventually I was able to track down all issues from those exception reports. I ended up building a service around this concept at http://bugcollect.com and integrate this with log4net, so I could get the reports in real time from all the deployments of my application (from all the clients).